# Using ransack to search from different controller action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a `PagesController` that contains two actions

```rb
def search
    @q = Listing.ransack(params[:q])
    @listings = @q.result(distinct: true)
    @listings = @listings.where(active: true).order("created_at DESC").page(params[:page]).per(12)
end
```

and

```rb
def home
end
```

now what I would like to achieve is that I could fire a search from the home path to the search path like

```
home.html.erb

<%= search_form_for @q, url: search_path do |f| %>
<%= f.search_field :listing_name_cont %>                
<%= f.submit 'Search' %>
```

but this returns `No Ransack Search object was provided to search_form_for` which It should since there is no `q` param passed to the home action. The only way I can get this to work is that if I modify the home action as follows

```rb
def home
    @q = Listing.ransack(params[:q])
end
```

but this doesn't seem reasonable since I'm not displaying any of the listings on the home page so I can imagine this will just slow down the page by quite a lot If I'm fetching a lot of listings. Is there any other way I could achieve this?

Comment: If I understand you correctly it won't slow down the page. Listing.ransack(params[:q]) called from home will just create a new empty ransack which doesn't fire any SQL. only when the form is submitted the SQL will run on the search method

Answer (score 0):

```
You can do <%= search_form_for @q, url: 'home' do |f| %>
```

`'home'` can be whatever you want the URL extension to be.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).